# warning errors don't apear in my visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, warnings

In program.cs file and in line that we choose first form,Iwant to show form1 when my application runs. But when my application runs, form2 apears.
I don't know what options I changed.
Not bad you know that when I change my codes and I want to close visual studio,there are no warning me to save and when I have an error in my codes,visual studio doesn't ask me that "you have an error in your application" or something like this.
Please help me to restore my defult options.
Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. It seems like there are at least three different questions that don't even make sense together.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Tools / Import and Export Settings / Reset all settings?

Can't say I've ever had Visual Studio fail to prompt me to save dirty files on exit, or on a build failure...

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new solution/project in visual studio and you don't save it visual studio won't track changes and/or ask you to save things. Hit save once to save you're data/solution.

In the main function you can tell wich form to start, if you're using vb.net you can use the project properties page too. You can use a right click in the solution explorer to set a 'startup project'